# How to repeat a pattern in SQL skipping weekends?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column patterns something like '1,2,3,4' and a column name frequency which represents how many times each pattern shall repeat. For ex.

I have a generated a pattern but not able to skip weekends, here is my current code -

```
;WITH TestCteNew (EmployeeId, ShiftId, StartDate, Enddate)AS (
SELECT
    employeeid.n.query('.[1]').value('.', 'INT') EmployeeId,
    shiftid.n.query('.[1]').value('.', 'INT') ShiftId
    ,StartDate, Enddate
FROM 
TestCte
CROSS APPLY employeeid.nodes('x') AS employeeid(n)
CROSS APPLY shiftid.nodes('x') AS shiftid(n)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(2) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 r_num FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS A , SYS.ALL_OBJECTS B) X)
,TestCteFinal(EmployeeId, ShiftId, SDate,r_num) AS (
SELECT EmployeeId, ShiftId, StartDate + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY r_num)-1 AS SD, x.r_num
FROM TestCteNew
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(2) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 r_num FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS A , SYS.ALL_OBJECTS B) X)
```

With the above code I am able to generate something like below

```
 Account DayOfWeek   Shifts   Shifts
    1      20201007    100        1
    2      20201107    100        1   (Saturday)
    3      20201207    100        2   (Sunday)
    4      20201307    100        2
    5      20201407    100        3
    6      20201507    100        3
    7      20201607    100        4
    8      20201707    100        4
                                  ...Same set of records above once again
```

Here the issue is my pattern is not skipping weekends, I want something like below.

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(10)= '1,2,3,4', @Frequency INT=2

Account DayOfWeek   Shifts   Shifts
1      20201007    100        1
2      20201107    100        0   (Saturday)
3      20201207    100        0   (Sunday)
4      20201307    100        1
5      20201407    100        2
6      20201507    100        2
7      20201607    100        3
8      20201707    100        3
9      20201807    100        0   (Saturday)
10     20201907    100        0   (Sunday)
12     20202007    100        4
13     20202107    100        4
14     20202207    100        1
15     20202307    100        1
```

I want to repeat the pattern in the above defined format.

Comment: `datepart(weekday, ...)`

Comment: By datepart I can get the day number but how shall I skip weekend while repeating my pattern.

Comment: Looks to that you'd just filter them out.

Comment: Filter and do what. I have used cross apply to repeat a pattern. So it might not be possible to achieve what I am trying to do here. If possible can you suggest how?

Comment: Post some usable data and somebody will probably take a closer look. Your definition of a pattern is not clear either.

Comment: Updated my question to be more precise. If it fine now?

Comment: You could really put more effort into being explicit about it but I think I get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo-code because you the source of the data isn't clear. You refer to a `TestCte` that isn't defined. The query never uses the `@Frequency` and `@Pattern` variables that head the desired outer. The output has an `Account` column that isn't mentioned anywhere else... But perhaps this approach will work better.

```
declare @Frequency int = 2;
declare @StartDt date = '20200710';
with num(n) as (
    select top (256) row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1
    from sys.all_objects
), dates(n, dt) as (
    select row_number() over (order by n), dateadd(day, n, @StartDt)
    from num
    -- filter weekend dates
    where datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, n, @StartDt)) between 1 and 5
)
select p.n, r.n, d.dt
from
    patterns as p -- this comes from xml? I'm going to assume these are numbered somehow
    inner join num as r /* repetitions */
        on r.n <= @Frequency -- I think something like "multiples" might be a better name
    inner join dates as d
        on d.n = @Frequency * p.n + r.n
```